# KeyError while accessing attributes of tags that exist - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The version of my python is 2.7

```
# -*- coding : utf - 8 -*-
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = urllib.urlopen('https://movie.douban.com/nowplaying/hangzhou')
html_data = resp.read().decode('utf-8')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data,'html.parser')
nowplaying_movie = soup.find_all('div',id = 'nowplaying')
print nowplaying_movie
# notice class_
nowplaying_movie_list = nowplaying_movie[0].find_all('li',class_ = 'list-item')
print nowplaying_movie_list

nowplaying_list = []
for item in nowplaying_movie_list :
    nowplaying_dict = {}
    nowplaying_dict['id'] = item['id']
    nowplaying_dict['name'] = item['data-title']
    nowplaying_movie_list.append(nowplaying_dict)
```

And the printed-out content of nowplaying_movie_list is

```
[<li class="list-item" data-actors="\u53e4\u5929\u4e50 / \u5434\u6a3e / \u6258\u5c3c\xb7\u8d3e" data-category="nowplaying" data-director="\u53f6\u4f1f\u4fe1" data-duration="101\u5206\u949f" data-enough="True" data-region="\u9999\u6e2f \u4e2d\u56fd\u5927\u9646" data-release="2017" data-score="7.5" data-showed="True" data-star="40" data-subject="26826398" data-title="\u6740\u7834\u72fc\xb7\u8d2a\u72fc" data-votecount="11357" id="26826398">\n<ul class="">\n<li class="poster">\n<a class="ticket-btn" data-psource="poster" href="https://movie.douban.com/subject/26826398/?from=playing_poster" target="_blank">\n<img alt="\u6740\u7834\u72fc\xb7\u8d2a\u72fc" class="" rel="nofollow" src="https://img3.doubanio
```

which I think is quite normal.

I want to extract the id and name of movies on the website and save them into a dict, however error indicates something wrong with the 'data-title'.

The error is

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Python27/movie
>   comments.py", line 19, in
>
> nowplaying_dict['name'] = item['data-title']
>
> KeyError: 'data-title'

I guess it is the problem of recognizing the `hyphen`, as I am pretty sure there exists the class "data-title" in the printed html file.

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: Actually, your code works for me, and I get `杀破狼·贪狼
战狼2
二十二
十万个冷笑话2
破·局
赛尔号大电影6：圣者无敌
星际特工：千星之城
极盗车神
赛车总动员3：极速挑战
心理罪
侠盗联盟
地球：神奇的一天
皮绳上的魂
鲛珠传
建军大业
三生三世十里桃花
恐怖毕业照2
海边的曼彻斯特
神偷奶爸3
我是谁的宝贝
大耳朵图图之美食狂想曲
闪光少女
龙之战
绝技情缘之艺魂`

Comment: That is strange, do you know why I cannot access the title?

Comment: Funny. I get an `IOError` sometimes, and other times it works. Something wrong with the site maybe? Can you print out the contents of `nowplaying_movie_dict` when you get this error?

Comment: You mean nowplaying_movie_list right?

Comment: Yeah, that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem some of the list items you scrape do not contain the `data-title` attribute. Everything else checks out, so why not just `catch` that exception?

```
nowplaying_list = []
for item in nowplaying_movie_list:
    try:
        nowplaying_dict = {}
        nowplaying_dict['id'] = item['id']
        nowplaying_dict['name'] = item['data-title']
        nowplaying_list.append(nowplaying_dict)
    except KeyError:
        pass

print(nowplaying_list)
```

Also, I noticed you're appending to the wrong list.

Comment: Just to note that since this has the effect of ignoring elements where an id or name element is not valid, then the OP could also prefilter those out with something like (this only includes elements that have a title attribute): `nowplaying_movie[0].find_all('li', class_='list-item', attrs={'data-title': True})`

Comment: Thanks , your answer is really helpful~

Comment: BTW, @JonClements,  seems like what you provide is the same as the one of using `try` ? Could you explain further the difference if possible?

Comment: @exteralvictor the try/except one gives each one a go even if it's not going to succeed and ignores the errors... by filtering before hand, you know it's not going to fail because of the key lookup as you're ignoring those without the key and you're also building a smaller list of candidates...

Comment: @exteralvictor if you just want to collection a list of dict of data never minding if you've got a title, then your entire code simplifies to: `nowplaying_list = [{k.rpartition('data-')[2]: v for k, v in el.attrs.items()} for el in soup.select('#nowplaying li.list-item')]` (you'll end up with the `class` and maybe other stuff in the dict you don't need, but meh... not a biggie)

Comment: A KeyError exception can be avoided by testing for `item.has_attr('data-title')` before using `item['data-title']`.  This applies to Python 3.11 and BeautifulSoup 4.12.